# Set JavaScript variable = null, or leave undefined?

Tags: javascript

When declaring variables at the top of the JavaScript function, is it best practice to set them equal to null, or leave as 'undefined'? Another way to ask, what circumstances call for each option below?

Option A:

```
var a = null,
    b = null;
```

Option B:

```
var a,
    b;
```

Comment: I'll go with option `b`

Comment: @Mr.Alien - agreed. There is no reason to use the `= null` version unless it actually matters that the variable values are `null` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Actually, `var a, b;` mightn't always *leave it `undefined`*. In former IE versions, you would need to change that piece of code to `var a = undefined, b = undefined;`, otherwise your code would generate an error while trying to access it (even if you were just trying to simply check if it has some value with `if (a && b)`, for example). In that case, an unset variable differs from `undefined`.

Comment: Another question, is there a difference in memory management https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339963/is-it-better-to-leave-variables-undefined-set-them-to-null-or-set-them-to-initi

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I declare them as undefined when I don't assign a value because they are undefined after all.

Comment: Then is it necessary to 'assign' undefined, because as you said they are undefined after all?

Comment: As mentioned it's not necessary to declare undefined, but also if you do declare undefined then when testing that value you won't know if you deliberately set it or if it was never actually set. This is why I prefer null in cases where there may not be a value.

Answer (score 61):

It depends on the context.

- "undefined" means this value does not exist. `typeof` returns "undefined"
- "null" means this value exists with an empty value. When you use `typeof` to test for  "null", you will see that it's an object. Other case when you serialize "null" value to backend server like asp.net mvc, the server will receive "null", but when you serialize "undefined", the server is unlikely to receive a value.

Answer (score 16):

Generally, I use null for values that I know can have a "null" state; for example

```
if(jane.isManager == false){
  jane.employees = null
}
```

Otherwise, if its a variable or function that's not defined yet (and thus, is not "usable" at the moment) but is supposed to be setup later, I usually leave it undefined.

Answer (score 9):

Generally speak I defined `null` as it indicates a human set the value and `undefined` to indicate no setting has taken place.

Answer (score 5):

I usually set it to whatever I expect to be returned from the function.

If a string, than i will set it to an empty string ='',  same for object ={} and array=[], integers = 0.

using this method saves me the need to check for null / undefined. my function will know how to handle string/array/object regardless of the result.

Answer (score 3):

The only time you need to set it (or not) is if you need to explicitly check that a variable *`a`* is set exactly to `null` or `undefined`.

```
if(a === null) {

}
```

...is not the same as:

```
if(a === undefined) {

}
```

That said, `a == null && a == undefined` will return `true`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/E3nqF/1/)

Comment: Checking for null in this case is not good. As it violates the "avoid null comparsions" best practice in javascript. You should compare against null only for DOM object (http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449328092/iidot-programming-practices/id2779483)

Comment: I don't agree; all we want to do is see if a variable is actually `null` or `undefined` - which are totally valid checks. I _do agree_ that in your cited example it's a bad idea to check against `null`, but that's just one case :)

Answer (score 3):

Be careful if you use this value to assign some object's property and call `JSON.stringify` later* - nulls will remain, but undefined properties will be omited, as in example below:

```js
var a, b = null;

c = {a, b};

console.log(c);
console.log(JSON.stringify(c)) // a omited
```

*or some utility function/library that works in similar way or uses `JSON.stringify` underneath

Answer (score 1):

There are two features of null we should understand:

1. **null** is an empty or non-existent value.
2. **null** must be assigned.

You can assign null to a variable to denote that currently that variable does not have any value but it will have later on. A null means absence of a value.

example:-

```
 let a = null;
 console.log(a); //null
```

Answer (score -19):

You can use `'';` to declaring NULL variable in Javascript

Comment: An empty string and `null` are very different things.