# Is it better to leave variables undefined, set them to null or set them to initial type values as far as memory management?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript is it better to define a value for variables, null for variables or leave them undefined?

Option A

```
var a;
```

Option B

```
var b = null;
```

Option C

```
var c = [];
```

Code

```
var items = null;

if (performAction) {
   items = getSelectedItems();
   performOtherAction(items);
}
```

IIRC if the runtime doesn't know the type a null or undefined value will allocate room for any object type. Although, if JIT sees the variable assigned a specific type then it can infer the type and then allocate for the memory for that type.

If you define and empty value it allocates room for that type (string, number, boolean, etc).

There is a similar question but this question doesn't include the option of setting them to the type you will eventually use nor does it ask about memory management between the three options.

[Set JavaScript variable = null, or leave undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474796/set-javascript-variable-null-or-leave-undefined)

Comment: Of interest: https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-memory-management/

Comment: There's no point setting the variable because JavaScript does not care; it literally does nothing of value except create an array you never use. (Unless, of course, you want to set it to some actual useful value.)

Comment: According to [ASM.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js) (a JavaScript subset designed to be better optimizable) a variable should be assigned when declared (and it should not be assigned to another type later)

Comment: Well that's probably true for ASM, and it's understandable why. Similarly (in modern environments) it's good to "pre-shape" objects when possible with an object initializer, because that helps the optimizer too. However for *almost all* modern web JavaScript purposes, browsers are extremely optimized. If something is slow (inside your browser) when you click on a mouse, the problem is almost certainly not caused by lack of such micro-optimizations.

Comment: As with most performance optimization questions, the answer will be: test it in your specific situation and see.

Comment: What do you mean by "*setting them to the type you will eventually use*"? Why do you not declare the variable with the real value, where you actually use it? It would help if you could show us your actual code as a concrete example.

Comment: @Bergi I added a similar example. Are you asking why I don't set the variable to a value at the top of the function? I like to declare variables at the top of the function for organization and readability and not throughout the function block. And there are a few cases where scope might be an issue that this type of organization prevents.